# why app keep crashing after updating to expo 48 from 45

Tags: android, react-native, expo, crash

I updated expo from 45 to 48. Now If I download a new apk on physical device, the app will crash once and run successfully on second time. If I run it on simulator, it keep staying on expo go app loading page and cannot open, no error log is showing. What is the possible reason?

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^4.6.5",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^4.7.3",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.171.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.282.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-sns": "^3.279.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.190.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.23.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.1.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.34",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.5",
    "aws-iot-device-sdk-v2": "^1.9.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1291.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.3.2",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-clipboard": "^4.1.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.3",
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "i18n-js": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react_native_mqtt": "^1.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-flip-card": "^3.5.7",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "stripe": "^11.8.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Did you update the „expo go“ app as well? Which error do you get? Do you try ```expo start -c```